# How server can ping Android application

Tags: android

In my Android application there is a requirement to ping Android application from Server, is it really possible? Or only possible way is to ping Server from Android app.

Please share your ideas on how server can ping Android application. Also share code snippets if you have

Thanks

Comment: use push notification(GCM) or xmpp services.

Comment: @user45678 : Agreed to Jolson that use any push notification services like GCM or Parse or any..!!

Comment: @user45678 You haven't specified which server you are using?

Comment: I can use my own server and develop a code, if that is possible!

Comment: For OP and all reacting on this post: An application cannot be pinged. . You can only ping an OS on a device.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Cloud Messaging for Android: [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Here is a good post for beginners. [Find Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

You can implement GCM Client and Server to ping your application instead of showing a notification. GCM allow to send data upto 4kb of payload.

Please go through How to implement GCM server and GCM Client on the link.